# What interfaces are programmable in the Nokia N73?

Tags: java, nokia, hardware-interface, n73

I have a [Nokia N73](http://www.s60.com/life/s60phones/displayDeviceOverview.do?deviceId=840) and I'd like to program it to **interface** with external hardware using any available interface. ([POP Port](http://pinouts.ru/CellularPhones-Nokia/nokia_pop_pinout.shtml)?)

Using any of the [available platforms:](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Resources_and_Information/Explore/Software_Platforms/S60/#flash)

- [Open C++](http://www.forum.nokia.com/openc)
- [Symbian C++](http://www.forum.nokia.com/main/resources/technologies/symbian/documentation/getting_started.html)
- [Java](http://www.forum.nokia.com/main/resources/technologies/java/documentation/getting_started.html)
- [Flash Lite](http://www.forum.nokia.com/main/resources/technologies/flash/index.html)
- [Python](http://www.forum.nokia.com/python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found:**

- [Java ME Serial Port](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/2a2ec089-6f2e-47cb-a150-d11a94eb80ad/MIDP_Using_Cable_Connection_In_Nokia_Devices_v1_0.zip.html), RS-232 CommConnection using Java ME MIDP
- [Wired Interfaces on Nokia mobiles](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Resources_and_Information/Explore/Mobile_Technologies/Connectivity_&_Interfaces/Wired_Interfaces/), USB, POP, AV, 2mm
- [Serial communication over USB](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/TSS000601_-_Serial_communication_over_USB_on_S60_3rd_Edition_devices), using the RComm API in Symbian C++
- [IR Serial communication](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Serial_communication), using the S60 Comms Server